# HiddenInput doesn't travel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, hidden-field

I have a form with these statements:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OriginalDailyTimeOption)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OriginalWorkWeekStartDay)
```

When I View Source, I see these elements in the form element, and when I submit the form, these properties are all properly returned.

Now, I read about using `[HiddenInput]` in my viewmodel, so I tried this:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = true)]
public int CompanyId { get; set; }

// Original values
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = true)]
public DayOfWeek OriginalWorkWeekStartDay { get; set; }

[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = true)]
public bool OriginalDailyTimeOption { get; set; }
```

and I removed the `@Html` statements that I had before.

Now, when I View Source, I do not see the elements in the form, and when I submit the form, the values do not show up at the controller action.  I had also tried the `HiddenInput` attribute without having `(DisplayValue = true)`, but I got the same results.  I also tried DisplayValue = false.

Is there something I am doing wrong with my HiddenInput attributes?  (For the record, I am testing with IE 11.)

Answer (score 1):

I found this in another post (by podiluska) when I searched for "difference between Html.HiddenFor & HiddenInput attribute":

"HiddenInput is an attribute on a field in the (view)model - which means that it can be used across multiple views and indicates that this field should be hidden wherever it is rendered by an EditorFor helper."

The MSDN page on HiddenInputAttribute says nothing about EditorFor, so that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Include a [HttpPost] Also make sure the hiddenfor's are in your form

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult action(Model model)
{
     Model _model = new Model();
     _model.CompanyId = model.CompanyId;
    etc...


}
```

Comment: The question is, why do I have to have the HiddenFor's in the form if I am using the HiddenInput attribute?  (And, for the record, although I didn't show it, I do have the HttpPost attribute for my action.)

Comment: The html form will only post values that are inside the form element on the form page. They will not be posted if they are outside the html form

Comment: The documentation for HiddenInputAttribute says, "Represents an attribute that is used to indicate whether a property or field value should be rendered as a hidden input element."  I take "be rendered" as putting it inside the form element.  If you understand, please tell me what HiddenInput is for.  Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325616/mvc-razor-hidden-input-and-passing-values this might help to explain some. Im sorry if this doesn't answer your question.