# Passing models to Razor views (partials, etc.)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

How can I transfer data/model between partial/views/controllers in C# MVC?

I'm trying to duplicate [this](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/mvc-view) example, but the `@model IEnumerable<MVC_BasicTutorials.Models.Student>` is given me an error, with red line under the `Model`

`_StudentList Partial.cshtml`

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC_BasicTutorials.Models.Student>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StudentName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.StudentId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.StudentId  }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.StudentId })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

`StudentController`:

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
 public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
IList<Student> students;

public StudentController()
{
    students = new List<Student>{ 
                    new Student() { StudentId = 1, StudentName = "John", Age = 18 } ,
                    new Student() { StudentId = 2, StudentName = "Steve",  Age = 21 } ,
                    new Student() { StudentId = 3, StudentName = "Bill",  Age = 25 } ,
                    new Student() { StudentId = 4, StudentName = "Ram" , Age = 20 } ,
                    new Student() { StudentId = 5, StudentName = "Ron" , Age = 31 } ,
                    new Student() { StudentId = 6, StudentName = "Chris",  Age = 17 } ,
                    new Student() { StudentId = 7, StudentName = "Rob",Age = 19  } ,
                };

}
// GET: Student
public ActionResult Index()
{

    return View(students);
}
}
```

`Index.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC_BasicTutorials.Models.Student>

<h3>Student List</h3>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@{
Html.RenderPartial("_StudentList", Model);
}
```

I read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11326470/2441637 but could not get it solved :( if I run the app, I get an error at `@foreach (var item in Model)` that is `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: is there a class named `Student` under a namespace of `MVC_BasicTutorials.Models`?

Comment: there is no `MVC_BasicTutorials.Models` at all, not sure where it should be and how

Comment: since the Student class is in your Student Controller.. the path is probably `{SolutionName}.Controllers.StudentController.Student`

Comment: Having the Full pah not worked, it worked only after I created a separate class with `[myExistingNameSpace].Model` thanks a lot for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Student` class is defined as a sub class of `StudentController`. So you need to use the proper namespace / fully qualified class name when using this class as the model type.

Change the first line to

```
@model IEnumerable<PutYourNameSpaceHere.StudentController.Student>
```

*You need to replace `PutYourNameSpaceHere` with the namespace under your `StudentController` class is*

**Or**

Move the `Student` class to a new file (or even existing), but under the namespace `MVC_BasicTutorials.Models`

```
namespace MVC_BasicTutorials.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
       public int StudentId { get; set; }
       public string StudentName { get; set; }
       public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When doing this, you need to make sure to have a using statement in your `StudentController` so that you can use this class

So add this as the first line of the `StudentController` class

```
@using MVC_BasicTutorials.Models
```

Comment: Having the Full pah not worked, it worked only after I created a separate class with `[myExistingNameSpace].Model` and there was no need for adding `@using MVC_BasicTutorials.Models` to run, but it showed a red line error in the VS so i added it.
Thanks for your support, if you tune your answer little bit based on my comment, I'll be happy to accept it and vote it up. thanks again