# Checkbox Click Form Submit in Razor Pages AspNetCore 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to (non-Ajax) get a checkbox to resubmit form in Razor Pages and reload the page / and catch the result in my OnPost method.

I have in my index.cshtml

```
@page  "{id:int?}"
@model IndexModel

<div class="text-center">
    <form action="post" name="form1">
        <strong>Filter:</strong> Hide Single Runs <input onclick="document.form1.submit()" asp-for="@Model.HideSingle" />        
        <hr />
```

And in my PageModel

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public bool HideSingle { get; set; } = true;

    public async Task OnPost(int? id, bool hideSingle)
    {
```

for say a starting page URL:

```
http://localhost:5000/TestRuns/1
```

The form submits on the checkbox click, but it ends up with a Url:

```
http://localhost:5000/TestRuns/post?HideSingle=false
```

Which obviously fails to resolve as I am expecting a route of http://localhost:5000/TestRuns/1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Asp.net Core form, the default method is `Get` which means for your current code, it send request with `Get` instead of post. You could specify the method with `post` like

```
<div class="text-center">
    <form method="post" name="form1">
        <strong>Filter:</strong> Hide Single Runs <input onclick="document.form1.submit()" asp-for="@Model.HideSingle" />
        <hr />
    </form>
</div>
```

For another way, you could explictly set the handler like

```
<div class="text-center">
    <form asp-page-handler="post" name="form2">
        <strong>Filter:</strong> Hide Single Runs <input onclick="document.form2.submit()" asp-for="@Model.HideSingle" />
        <hr />
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input onclick="document.form1.submit()" />
```

is using JavaScript to submit the form. Do you want the page to post back, since you're not using Ajax (from your question)?

You want the call from your page to end up being `http://localhost:5000/TestRuns/post?id=1&HideSingle=false`. Is id required for your post to work (it's unclear with `OnPost(int? id..)`?

I order to get both values, you'll need to have [hidden form values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325616/mvc-razor-hidden-input-and-passing-values) or multiple `<input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />`. You need 1 for hideSingle and on for the id.